"Symmetric" photon polarization rotation
The usual linear polarization matrix/operator for a photon or classical light transforming from some combination of $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$ to another is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is it possible to have a rotation operator which is "symmetric" such as:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If not, what is the principle that does not allow it. If possible (bonus points) how would you actually construct one (standard components, PBS, BS, waveplates, etc, or...)?

The first matrix you have written down rotates a two dimensional vector by $\theta$ degrees counterclockwise, and is not inherently related to quantum mechanics - it is a mathematical object. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.

As to Martin's comment, yes, this matrix can be used in other non-quantum contexts, as many other matrix/operators can. See
link
for the intimate relationship between linear algebra and quantum mechanics. The question is can you legitimately have an operator in the form of the second matrix for polarization transformations or does that violate some fundamental principle.

I don't think it is neccesarily true that the "usual linear polarization matrix" is like the written one. If you allow complex numbers to describe the phase of the $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$, you have a more general matrix. It can have the same forms as for transformation of spin $\frac12$ states, including the symmetric $\binom{\ \cos\theta\quad i\sin\theta}{i\sin\theta\quad\cos\theta\ }$

No it is not possible.  The transformation of polarization is a $U(2)$ transformation and must be unitary so as to preserve the total photon number.  The determinant of a unitary matrix $u$ satisties $\vert \text{det}(u)\vert^2=1$ but your matrix has determinant
$\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$ so is not unitary unless $\theta=0,\pi/2$.
The most general form of a $2\times 2$ unitary matrix is
$$
u=e^{-i\varphi}\begin{pmatrix} w&-z\\ z^* &w^*\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $ww^*+zz^*=1$.  It is convenient to write $w=e^{i\alpha}\cos(\beta)$ and $z=e^{i\gamma}\sin(\beta)$ and using this you can adjust the phases $\alpha,\gamma, \varphi$ and angle $\beta$ to give you any matrix you need.
IIRC the quarter waveplate is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 &\pm i\end{pmatrix}
$$
so in this case $\beta=0$, $\varphi=\alpha$ and $\alpha=\pm \pi/4$ will do the trick.
